# How to get sum of duration if next row value same as current row value in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

i have a table with

```
id | Loc_id | time_in             | time_out            | duration | prev
1  | Loc A  | 2020-06-16 06:58:29 | 2020-06-16 07:05:45 | 7        | Null
2  | Loc B  | 2020-06-16 07:07:20 | 2020-06-16 07:16:43 | 9        | Loc A
3  | Loc B  | 2020-06-16 07:18:25 | 2020-06-16 07:23:28 | 5        | Loc B
4  | Loc C  | 2020-06-16 07:25:11 | 2020-06-16 07:28:16 | 3        | Loc B
5  | Loc D  | 2020-06-16 07:28:16 | 2020-06-16 07:33:01 | 4        | Loc C
6  | Loc D  | 2020-06-16 07:34:44 | 2020-06-16 07:39:05 | 4        | Loc D
7  | Loc B  | 2020-06-16 07:40:47 | 2020-06-16 07:44:16 | 3        | Loc D
```

i want to get the sum of duration if next row value same as current row value as

```
id | Loc ID | duration
1  | Loc A  | 7
2  | Loc B  | 14
3  | Loc C  | 3
4  | Loc D  | 8
5  | Loc B  | 3
```

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `SUM()` window function to create the groups that you want and then aggregate:

```
select t.loc_id, sum(t.duration) duration
from (
  select *, sum(loc_id <> coalesce(prev, loc_id)) over (order by id) grp
  from tablename                        
) t
group by t.grp, t.loc_id
```

or if you want also an `id` column:

```
select t.grp + 1 id, t.loc_id, sum(t.duration) duration
from (
  select *, sum(loc_id <> coalesce(prev, loc_id)) over (order by id) grp
  from tablename                        
) t
group by t.grp, t.loc_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=55891ced7320011a7d163293fce6bf06).
Results:

```
> id | loc_id | duration
> -: | :----- | -------:
>  1 | Loc A  |        7
>  2 | Loc B  |       14
>  3 | Loc C  |        3
>  4 | Loc D  |        8
>  5 | Loc B  |        3
```